# How to get a consecutive same set of character from the string which are stored in array ? For example' INPUT: sword|word|cord output: ord

Tags: c#

how to get consecutive set of character from a string which are stored in a array?
for example:
input:
sword
cord
word
OUTPUT:
ord

Comment: That´s not "consecutive", but "common". Anyway: what did you try already? There are plenty of similar questions around, just **search** for them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [tour] and [ask]. You should show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static String findstem(String[] arr)
    {
        // Determine size of the array  
        int n = arr.Length;

        // Take first word from array as reference  
        String s = arr[0];
        int len = s.Length;

        String res = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= len; j++)
            {

                // generating all possible substrings  
                // of our reference string arr[0] i.e s  
                String stem = s.Substring(i, j - i);
                int k = 1;
                for (k = 1; k < n; k++)

                    // Check if the generated stem is  
                    // common to to all words  
                    if (!arr[k].Contains(stem))
                        break;

                // If current substring is present in  
                // all strings and its length is greater  
                // than current result  
                if (k == n && res.Length < stem.Length)
                    res = stem;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

I found a solution here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-common-substring-array-strings/